# Почему таблицы смещаются непонятным образом?

Tags: html, css

[image]

Пишу вот такой код:

```
<table border="1px">
<tr>
    <td style="width:650px; height:30px;"></td>
<tr>

<tr>
    <td  style="width:650px; height:16px;"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td  style="width:100px; height:100px;"></td>
    <td  style="width:550px; height:100px;"></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Третье поле ведь должно разделиться на две колонки по 100 и 550 пикселей! Почему удваивается второе поле и смещается в сторону??? Я уже не знаю что делать с ним!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Читаем про [объединение колонок таблицы](http://htmlbook.ru/html/td/colspan)

```
<table border="1px">
<tr>
    <td style="width:650px; height:30px;" colspan="2"></td>
<tr>

<tr>
    <td  style="width:650px; height:16px;" colspan="2"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td  style="width:100px; height:100px;"></td>
    <td  style="width:550px; height:100px;"></td>
</tr>

</table>
```